# unrecognized field, not marked as ignorable

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, objectmapper

I get an error while trying to fill fields of a list of objects using ObjectMapper

```
public class FormMap {
    private String id;
    private String strengthRouteFormId;
    private String fdaid;
    private String formName;
    private String formDescription;
    private String ncitQuantityUnitTermId;
    private String ncitStrengthFormTermId;
    private String ncitId;
    private String ncitSubsetCode;
    private String ncpdpSubsetPreferredTerm;
    private String ncitCode;
    private String ncpdpPreferredTerm;
    private String ncitPreferredTerm;
    private String ncitDefinition;
    private StrengthRouteForm strengthRouteForm;
}

public class StrengthRouteForm {
    private String id;
    private String medicationId;
    private String strength;
    private String routeName;
    private String gsForm;
    private String alternativeFormName;
    private String clinicalDoseFormName;
    private String normalizedFormName;
    private String topLevelDoseFormName;
    private List<FormMap> formMaps;
}
```

I have this 2 classes and I want to create a List of StrengthRouteForm using ObjectMapper and a Json

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();   
objectMapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);
List<StrengthRouteForm> strengthRouteForms = null;
strengthRouteForms = Arrays.asList(objectMapper.readValue("string json", StrengthRouteForm[].class));
```

and i get this error:

```
Unrecognized field "FormMap" (class com.cgm.us.ais.core.model.StrengthRouteForm), not marked as ignorable
```

JSON may look like this:

```
"StrengthRouteForm": [
                {
                    "Strength": "0.25",
                    "RouteName": "Oral",
                    "GSForm": "Oral tablet",
                    "AlternativeFormName": "Oral Solid",
                    "ClinicalDoseFormName": "Oral tablet",
                    "NormalizedFormName": "Oral tablet",
                    "TopLevelDoseFormName": "Oral preparations - solid forms",
                    "FormMap": [
                        {
                            "FDAID": "500",
                            "FormName": "Tab",
                            "FormDescription": "Tablet",
                            "NCItQuantityUnitTermID": "106",
                            "NCItStrengthFormTermID": "447",
                            "NCItId": "106",
                            "NCItSubsetCode": "C89510",
                            "NCPDPSubsetPreferredTerm": "NCPDP QuantityUnitOfMeasure Terminology",
                            "NCItCode": "C48542",
                            "NCPDPPreferredTerm": "Tablet",
                            "NCItPreferredTerm": "Tablet Dosing Unit",
                            "NCItDefinition": "A dosing unit equal to the amount of active ingredient(s) contained in a tablet."
                        },
                        {
                            "FDAID": "500",
                            "FormName": "Tab",
                            "FormDescription": "Tablet",
                            "NCItQuantityUnitTermID": "106",
                            "NCItStrengthFormTermID": "447",
                            "NCItId": "447",
                            "NCItSubsetCode": "C89508",
                            "NCPDPSubsetPreferredTerm": "NCPDP StrengthForm Terminology",
                            "NCItCode": "C42998",
                            "NCPDPPreferredTerm": "Tablet",
                            "NCItPreferredTerm": "Tablet Dosage Form",
                            "NCItDefinition": "A solid composed of a mixture of that active and/or inert ingredient(s) are pressed or compacted together, usually in the form of a relatively flat and round, square or oval shape."
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
```

My question is: how can I make this list: **formMaps** to map **FormMap** from JSON

Comment: Either you rename `private List<FormMap> formMaps;` to `formMap` or you place a property giving the name of the field in JSON. AFAIK it is `@JsonProperty("FormMap") private List<FormMap> formMaps;`

Comment: Smutje thanks for your answer. @JsonProperty works for me in this case. unfortunately i can't give you a thumbs up because my rep is too low :(

Comment: I re-write is as an answer, one moment please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable changing the name of the target Java field for a given JSON property, the annotation `@JsonProperty` can be used. In your case, instead of being forced to rename `private List<FormMap> formMaps` to `formMap`, the annotation

```
@JsonProperty("FormMap")
private List<FormMap> formMaps;
```

can be used.